# cancan & many_to_many associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, many-to-many, cancan

I'm trying to write a rule for many_to_many association. Because of the association table some results are duplicated.

The code in my ability is:
I have many Users that have many Groups and i want to show all Post that their author belongs to a group the same as the current_user's group.
can :read, Post, :user => { :group => { :id => user.groups.collect { |g| g.id } } }

I took the generated SQL from the log and ran it in MySql query builder. The duplications appear at the SQL level.

How can i get rid of the duplicated results ?!

**UPDATE 1:**

The generated SQL:
SELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` INNER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `posts`.`user_id` INNER JOIN `groups_users` ON `groups_users`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` INNER JOIN `groups` ON `groups`.`id` = `groups_users`.`group_id` WHERE (`groups`.`id` IN (1, 2)) LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0

i updated my post to include the generated SQL. the problem is that if a user belongs to 2 groups than i get duplicated results. isn't there a way to "distinct" the results ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use a named scope in order to get DISTINCT results for my query.

I added this to post.rb:
`named_scope :unique_posts, :select => "DISTINCT 'posts'.*"`

Now i get distinct results when i call @posts.unique_posts

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [`uniq`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000276) Array method after you've returned the group IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
can :read, Post, :user => { :group => { :id => user.groups.collect { |g| g.id } } }
```

Try:

```
can :read, Post, :user => {:group => { :id => user.groups.map(&:id).uniq } }
```